# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred while debugging windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

the issue was resolved and the code executed successfully

Comment: It is because you are missing 'PhoneTitlePanelStyle' resource. So either you can add the style or you can remove that style reference from the xaml.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory.  You are trying to use a style of PhoneTitlePanelStyle where it does not exist